# cannot define new methods on non-local type models.Meter

Tags: go, go-modules

I want to put all my models in a shared `Common` lib.

So, I made a new repo: `gitlab.com/xxx/common`

Inside I put a package: `models`

Here is the definition of an object:

```
type Meter struct {
    ID           string
    OperationID  string
    Type         ConsoProd
    Unit         string
    Timestep     time.Duration
    Measures     []Measure 
    FetchMethod  AcquisitionMethod
    Metadata     interface{}
}
```

Now, I want to use it in an external project, I do:

```
go get gitlab.com/xxx/common
```

And Go Modules will download it.

I import use it like that:

```
import "gitlab.com/xxx/common/models"

//String transparent method
func (meter models.Meter) String() string {
    var stringifyMeter string
    stringifyMeter += "Meter " + meter.ID + " is a " + meter.Type.String() + " and compute in operation #" + meter.OperationID + "."
    return stringifyMeter
}
```

But Goland will not resolve it, and when I compile, I get:

```
cannot define new methods on non-local type models.Meter
```

Why is it happening and what can I do to fix it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not allowed to define methods outside the package where the type is defined. This leaves you with a couple of options:

1. Define the methods in the `models` package. That's the simplest approach when dealing with your own code but of course won't work for 3rd-party types.
2. Create a regular function instead of a method (`func String(meter models.Meter) string`). That might be less idiomatic, though (especially for the `String` method), and also does not have access to private fields (unless you define the function in the `models` package, in which case you could just define the method instead).
3. Create a new type embedding the original type. That would be a bit cumbersome to use but allows you to extend existing behavior. Something like this:

`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    myTime := MyTime{time.Now()}
    fmt.Println(myTime)        /* behaves as time.Time */ 
    fmt.Println(myTime.Foo())  /* also has extra methods */
}

type MyTime struct {
  time.Time
}

func (m MyTime) Foo() string {
  return "foo"
}
```

Comment: Ok ! Option one make sense ! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Simple,

```
import ...bla/bla/Meter

type extended Meter
```

Ref: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31631#issuecomment-486075295